# UIView animations stopping on pop after fast swipe back from push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, animation

I have a tab bar controller and a view controller A inside it, and vc A has a push segue to another view controller B.

Also I have a button in my tab bar item which is animating for 10 seconds then in completion animates back to its initial state.

Everything works fine, animation doesn't stop on push or pop (because it's called on child vc, so my tab bar controller doesn't disappear) except when I push my A controller to B, then pop B to A with a fast swipe.

After fast swipe all animations stop, but because I have a chain of two animations, second one is called in first ones' completion block. So my button just freezes and is not interactable, because its animation is still "in progress", but the second animation never ends because fast swipe disabled UIVIew animations. Here's the code sample:

```
- (void)animateButton {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5];
                             myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:2f animations:^{
                                 myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                             } completion:^(BOOL finished2) {
                                 //
                             }];
                         }];
    }
}
```

So it freezes in the completion:`^(BOOL finished)` block, and completion:`^(BOOL finished2)` is never called.

P.S. I can get completion:`^(BOOL finished2)` being called if I write dispatch_async:

```
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2f animations:^{
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                             });
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished2) {
                             self.animating = NO;
                         }];
                     }];
```

but it is still without animation for 2 seconds, it just immediately goes to completion:^(BOOL finished2) (I guess because all UIView animations are stopped because of fast swipe)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm with the same problem here. I realized that I have one view that I bring to front and never send it back again, I only turn it hidden. To fix this I added a code to start after my transition animation which send my view to back again. This solved the problem, but the view blinks before appears again: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration, execute: { view.sendSubview(toBack: myView) }

Comment: nope, still seeking

Comment: I have the opposite problem - I run animation and need to pop view controller. Animation continues playing and overlaps the previous screen on transition.